# something wrong with the navbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

i have a problem with the navbar it works fine on full width but when i shrink the page the menu button appears and all but it is not working and i can't seem to figure out where is the problem is located in my code

```
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md"> 
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">CANDY</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navLinks">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="navLinks" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Tickets</a>
     </li>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing HTML Markup for Bootstrap 5 and importing Bootstrap 4.1.3.
One of the key differences is:

Bootstrap 5 (As per your code):
`<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navLinks">`

Bootstrap 4:
`<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks">`

Two options:

1. Change your HTML to the HTML markup for a `navbar` as per https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/
2. Change your bootstrap imports to Bootstrap 5 (**preferred**):

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the css link? You may also modify the top javascript bootstrap link by doing something like this.

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: yes i did in the head element